# Locale installation and setting on Fedora have no effect

Tags: fedora, terminal, locale, language

I was trying to install Chinese language support for a Fedora 26 Server hosted on Digital Ocean, multiple steps have been taken but I still couldn't get it right.

The language and charset I was trying to install is `zh_CN.UTF-8`

## Solutions taken so far:

- Setting `%_install_langs all` (which was previously `%_install_langs C:en:en_US:en_US.UTF-8` as the cloud provider default) in `/etc/rpm/macros.image-language-conf`, and then `$ dnf reinstall glibc-common`, according to this Super User post *[linux - How do I install/generate all locales on Fedora?](https://superuser.com/questions/959380/how-do-i-install-generate-all-locales-on-fedora)*.
- Installing `langpacks-zh_CN` using `$ dnf install langpacks-zh_CN`.
- Installing `glibc-langpack-zh` and `man-pages-zh-CN`, both of which are weak dependencies of `langpacks-zh_CN`, and somehow the latter is not installed when installing `langpacks-zh_CN`.
- Setting `LANG=zh_CN.UTF-8` and `LC_ALL=zh_CN.UTF-8` in `/etc/locale.conf`.
- Setting `export LANG=zh_CN.UTF-8` and `export LC_ALL=zh_CN.UTF-8` in `~/.bashrc`.

## What have been different:

- When using `$ date`, the prompt is now in correct language as `2017年 10月 20日 星期五 18:31:34 UTC`.
- However, anything else is still English, including `man` prompts, `dnf` prompts, `nano` prompts, etc.
- ***But the same commands work perfectly well on a local Fedora Server VM.***

## Noticed situation: *(but not sure if there are right or how to solve)*

- I found`/usr/share/locale/zh_CN/LC_MESSAGES` has fewer files in comparison with the VM on my Mac. While the VM on my Mac has tens of files in the folder (the translation project has been there for years), the cloud remote Droplet has only 1, and that is `libc.mo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After changing the settings as you have, you'll need to `dnf reinstall` any packages which are missing translations (not everything uses the langpacks feature yet). For example:

```
dnf reinstall dnf
```

and then you'll have translations for DNF. Repeat this for any other packages which are missing translations.

This will also happen as bugfix and security updates come in for the packages, and of course any new packages which come in after you've made the config change will bring translations along.

Comment: Wow! That was mind-blowning! Definitely didn't think of reinstalling `dnf`! And Chinese now works of `dnf`!